# How do I enable type resolution in detekt?

Tags: detekt

detekt is alerting me about the `SpreadOperator` rule.  According to [this issue](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/issues/554), the rule can be suppressed in certain circumstances when type resolution is enabled.  I can't find any documentation or examples of how to enable type resolution, though.  I can see that the cli options `--jvm-target` and `--classpath` seem to be related to type resolution, but it's unclear how to actually turn on type resolution, (or verify that it is already on).

How do enable type resolution in detekt and verify that it is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has this problem, you need to update detekt to the newest version (for now `1.3.1`). This version introduces new task: `detektMain` which enables type resolution

[image]